# In the Telophase Topology, what precisely is meant by "local neighborhood basis"?

Tags: general-topology

Steen and Seebach, in their Counterexamples in Topology (2ed, 1978) define the "telophase topology" as:

"Let $(X, \tau)$ be the topological space formed by adding to the ordinary closed unit interval $[0,1]$ another right-hand end point, say $1^*$, with the sets $(a,1) \cup \{1^*\}$ as a local neighborhood basis."

I question the term "local neighborhood basis", which is not defined anywhere in S&S. The relevant entry in the $\pi$-base website https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000065/properties/P000016 (which is itself a catalogue of topological spaces which subsumes S&S) refers to it as a "local basis", but does not then actually defined what is meant in this context. However, there are two terms in general use, "local basis" and "neighborhood basis" that mean subtly different things but appear to be generally interchangeable in usage, and it is not at all clear whether they are indeed genuinely equivalent.

My understanding is that:

a '''local basis''' at $x$ is a set $\mathcal B$ of open neighborhoods of $x$ such that $\forall U \in \tau: x \in U \implies \exists H \in \mathcal B: H \subseteq U$

while $\mathcal B$ is a '''neighborhood basis''' at $x$ if and only if for each neighborhood $N$ of $x$, there is an $M \in \mathcal B$ such that $M \subseteq N$

which I believe to be a strictly weaker notion than a '''local basis'''. Which one is actually referred to here? I can't find any discussion about this in the online literature. While S&S has a comprehensive bibliography, it does not match the citations with their appearance in the text.

Comment: weaker notion? More collections can be neighbourhood bases, so it's the more usable notion, because they serve the same purposes. A local base is always a neighbourhood base, but not vice versa.

Comment: I had always been led to understand that if A implies B then A is stronger than B, so under that criterion, "T is a local basis" is stronger than "T is a neighborhood basis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local base for $x$ is defined in S&S as a collection of open neighbourhoods of $x$ such that every open set of $X$ that contains $x$, contains a member of that collection as a subset.

Neighbourhood base is (in most texts that I know) the analogous notion of a filterbase for the filter of all neighbourhoods of $x$: collection of neighbourhoods of $x$ (in the general send, so they need not be open, e.g.) such that every neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ contains a member of that collection. This is a notion that exists in any filter, specialised to the specific case of the neighbourhood filter of $x$ (in a given space). So a local base is a special case of a neighbourhood base.

A space $X$ is called first countable iff it has a countable local base at every point, and this is the same as saying it has a countable neighbourhood base at any point. Or in terms of cardinal invariants that $\chi(X)=\aleph_0$ (i.e. the character of $X$ is countable).

We can define a topological space by specifying a neighbourhood filter at every point, and also by specifying a local base at every point. The axioms to check (that it defines a well-defined unique topology) are then slightly different for these two cases. See all sort of text books for this.

In the telophase topology they actually specify a local base at $1^\ast$, if you want to be pedantic. But in this "definition of a space" phase these are often used interchangeably. It often doesn't matter much which you specify, it's often clear what the intended open sets will be, as it is in this case.

So for first countability/character or definitional purposes (or continuity checking purposes) it doesn't matter much which notion we use. It is convenient so be able to say $X$ is Hausdorff iff it has a neighbourhood base of closed sets etc.

So I'd say that in this case S&S should her stated "local base" to avoid possible confusion. But the book is IMO not intended as a study book for beginning students, but for researchers or teachers needing a lot of examples to get intuition for some notions or as to why some implications between properties hold or not, all collected in one place with sketches of proofs, and a handy table for reference. A nice treasure trove for exam questions for teachers as well. Not a text book to study topology, but a companion text.

Comment: Yes I understand that it is not a study text. But on a certain level it has to have a certain level of usefulness, and that begins and ends with whether the information in it is accurate and complete and consistent. And if there is anything in there which is unclear and/or inaccurate, then that anything needs to be picked up on.

Comment: @PrimeMover The text must be seen in context. It's probably sometimes inconsistent because the examples come from many sources. The book is never going to change; there will not be an errata page. There will always be small things that a reader must infer, understand orwork out him/her self. It's part of doing maths. Papers are the same way.

Comment: But your answer is sufficient. I think what you are saying is "in this case it is immaterial because they are the same thing for a first-countable space". Incidentally, despite the fact that I seem to come across as one, I am not a "beginning student", I have an MMath which includes a basic grounding of topology, I'm just trying to apply what I know to a more-or-less challenging project, that of giving S&S a thorough and critical appraisal, during the course of which I need to check facts and details with others in the mathematical community.

Comment: @PrimeMover the intended audience forS&S is people who do topology a lot, professionally. Not mathematicians from other fields, primarily.

Comment: Be that as it may, this is the task that I have assigned myself to.

Comment: @PrimeMover planning a paper on it?

Comment: putting it on ProofWiki